# How to use "is prohibitive" in a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which of the following sentences is correct? Should I use "to" or "for"?

> Unfortunately, the cost for an attorney is prohibitive **to** me as a
>   university student.
>
> Unfortunately, the cost for an attorney is prohibitive **for** me as a
>   university student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct.

See the following examples from Reverso.context.net:

Malaysia is fully aware of the high costs involved in setting up such infrastructure; 
it may in fact be ***prohibitive to*** 
many developing countries.

An insurance scheme is operational on each side, though immediate concerns have been raised about the price, which is proving to be ***prohibitive for*** individuals on both sides.